# GIT not functionnal on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, git

I am trying to use GIT to manage my computing projects. But all commands using GIT do not respond on my terminal. For example if I try `git --version` followed by entry keyboard typing,  a blank line appear and wait until ever. If I type again the entry key on my keyboard the command line is again available but nothing appear. It's the same for all git function that I type.

Do you have any solution or explanation for this ?

Comment: does it happen only with git commands? how did you get git?

Comment: I tried this. I resintall with the git-1.7.12-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg but it's the same !

Comment: I think GIT was presintalled on my mac. I have troubles only with GIT.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the Developer Tools, if you have Xcode installed.

**Solution using Xcode**
Open up Xcode go to *Preferences > Downloads*, and update *Command line tools*.

**Solution without Xcode**
Go to https://developer.apple.com/ and find and download the *Command Line Tools Lion*

Comment: The question has **Lion** in the title???

Comment: My bad, but same principle applies. I will edit my answer, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: I have Xcode up to date even if I don't use it. It's to complex for me to handle Python projects. I am trying ...

Comment: You don't need to use xcode for developing, just download the Command line tools, which should fix Git throughout OS X.